# Shotwell crop menu opens blank

Tags: shotwell

When I open an image in Shotwell and click crop, the crop menu appears blank. I have attached a screenshot below. It seems like a bug. Is there a way to solve it and make menu appear correctly. The Shotwell version is 0.15.0. I run Ubuntu 13.10. My CPU is Intel 3rd Gen. CI5 and chipset is Intel 77.

[image]

Comment: 5 years passed..but same problem! version 0.18 on Ubuntu 14.04. did you find a solution?